# Entity Framework A second operation was started Error, despite await

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dbcontext

I have this list of names (`List<string>`) and want to map them to entities from the database. If there is an entity with the given name, just return it. If not, create and return it.

```cs
public async Task<List<Element>> MapStringsToEntities(List<strings> raws) 
{
   var result = new List<Elements>();
   foreach (var raw in raws)
   {
      var element = await _context.Elements
           .Where(t => t.Name.ToLower().Equals(raw))
           .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
              
           if (element == null)
           {
               element = new Element(raw);
               await _context.Elements.AddAsync(raw);
           }

      result.Add(element);
   }

   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   return result;
}
```

Although I'm awaiting the call to `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` I still get an error:

```
InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed. 
This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext.
```

The class where this method lives has a field of type `MyAppContext`:

```
private readonly MyAppContext _context;
```

And a constructor:

```
public ElementsService(MuAppContext ctx)
{
   this._context = ctx;
}
```

In `Startup.cs`, the context is initialized like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services              
       .AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString:DbString"])
    );
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You only get an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` (or something) back from the `.Where` and therefore actual execution is still delayed until you ask for it to be enumerated. You need to materialise the result by calling `.ToList()` (or whatever) to force it to run the query and load the results into memory before you try to use the connection again.

Comment: None of the code shown stores an unenumerated `IQueryable` for later execution.

Comment: It's inside the `element`. Really: add `.ToList()` after `.Where()`.

Comment: The only `Where` in the entire question is already immediately evaluated.  It's return value is not stored for later execution.  Adding a `ToList` would make the code perform worse (or it would once they solve the error they have on that line) and do nothing to solve the problem.